# Design pattern name for class that defines the flow between interfaces

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have two interfaces, unaware of each other.

```
public interface IListener
{
    event SignalEventHandler SignalReceived;
}

public interface IDevice
{
    Task HandleSignalAsync();
}
```

Rather than making each listener call a device directly or pass listeners into device implementations, I'd like to keep them decoupled and define the flow separately. For example:

```
public class MyApplicationFlow
{
    private readonly IListener _listener;
    private readonly IDevice _device;

    public MyApplicationFlow(IListener listener, IDevice device)
    {
        _listener = listener;
        _device = device;

        _listener.SignalReceived += ListenerOnSignalReceived;
    }

    private async void ListenerOnSignalReceived(object sender, SignalEventArgs args)
    {
        try
        {
            await _device.HandleSignalAsync();
            // do more stuff in real scenario

            args.ProgressReporter.ReportComplete();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            args.ProgressReporter.ReportError(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

There could be several `IDevice` and `IListener` implementations passed into the flow.

[image: Please excuse the poor diagram!]

The listeners and devices seem to follow the Adaptor pattern. But what about `MyApplicationFlow`?

- A [Mediator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern) defines the interactions between components, but here the objects are different types and unaware of the parent class.
- A [Facade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) encapsulates several subsystems, but here the subsystems are not hidden; they are injected into the constructor.

I'm not even sure if this would be a Behavioural or Structural pattern.

Is there a common name for a class that defines the flow between objects? Something I can use as a suffix for the class names that follow this pattern e.g. `Manager`, `Coordinator`, `Connector` (preferably something already used in the .NET framework).

Or, as I can't find anything, am I barking up the wrong tree? Is there a better way to achieve this decoupling?

Comment: There are not patterns here, just code

Comment: This is just dependency injection

Comment: Fair enough - I guess not everything is a pattern! Any help on how I can improve this question? Not sure I understand the downvotes.

Comment: I heard this quote recently: "No matter how much we say we love creativity on a conscience level, we subconsciously despise and fear it because it presents a level of uncertainty." Perhaps people are down voting to reflect their unconscionable disability to peg your question. I always find it a form of discouragement and bullying. If they can't provide an answer other than a down vote it reflects on them - not you. Unless you're a troll - then it's definitely you.

Comment: It is rather discouraging. If the answer is "no, this is not a common pattern" then I'd rather that just be the answer, rather than the downvote, implying that the question itself is unclear or unhelpful.

Comment: This kind of questions seem to be more like a quiz... see my code and tell me what design pattern is using my code...

Comment: The code is a simplified example to try explain the pattern, not my actual code, but perhaps I am still going into too much detail? The general idea is to decouple a signal handler (usually hardware in my cases) and a signal listener (an API endpoint or push notification). I could make every listener call the devices, but I would be repeating the same flow in each implementation. Any tips on how to better explain this in my question?

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, based on your names it seems like you have your listener and device backwards. Meaning, you seem to be listening to a signal sent from the listener and sending it to the device which seems backwards. Listeners imply listening to signals not sending signals in my opinion.

But otherwise I think what you have here is just a message passing system. Rather than directly communicating together you have a message dispatcher which receives messages from one component and sends them off to another. If you expand on what you have there rather than having a single device and a single listener you could establish any number of connections. You would then queue incoming messages and dispatch them to listeners based on those connections.

```
interface IListener {
  void send(ISender sender, IMessage message);
}
interface ISender { }
interface IMessage { }
interface IPending {
  ISender from;
  IMessage message;
}

class Dispatcher {
  private Queue<IPending> messages = new Queue<IPending>();
  private Dictionary<ISender, List<IListener>> connections = new Dictionary<ISender, List<IListener>>();

  public void connect(ISender sender, IListener listener) {
    if (connections[sender] == null) {
      connections[sender] = new List<IListener>();
    }

    connections[sender].add(listener);
  }

  public void remove(ISender sender, IListener listener) { ... } // removes connection from connections

  public void send(ISender from, IMessage message) {
    messages.push({ from, message });
  }

  public void next() { // called in a loop, perhaps in a background thread
    if (messages.peek()) {
      var message = messages.pop();
      foreach(var listener in connections[message.from]) {
        listener.send(sender, message);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The listener awaits a (kind of) push notification and the device is some hardware that performs an action when the push is received. In one real-world implementation, I pass a `ProgressReporter` in the `EventArgs`. Understand the confusion so I'll update the question to reflect this!

Answer (score -1):

My first thought was it sounds like a variant of the observer pattern, except in your case the observer isn't directly observing.  I found this variant called Event / Emitter / Target that sounds pretty close.  https://github.com/millermedeiros/js-signals/wiki/Comparison-between-different-Observer-Pattern-implementations

Edit--I've actually changed my mind.  This is pub-sub messaging. The IDevice classes are sending, the middle class is receiving the messages and the IListener is subscribing.

Comment: There's nothing about this that is the observer pattern.

Comment: I disagree.  The observer pattern is a software design pattern in which an object, called the subject, maintains a list of its dependents, called observers, and notifies them automatically of any state changes, usually by calling one of their methods.  In this case the listener is receiving signals via an intermediary, which defines how the signals interact - which is what makes it different than a straight out observer, but to say there's nothing about this that is observer - I disagree.

Comment: And at least I had the stones to attempt a helpful answer with the risk of a down vote versus hiding under the comments section.  If you disagree, state why - support your answer so we can have a discussion.

Comment: You disagree with me, that's fine. I stated why I didn't agree and there nothing else to add. You had the stones indeed, and I've done that many times too. Someone decided to downvote you, well you just accept it and move on. However you shouldn't take this personally - votes are for the *content*, not the person, note that the hover text on the downvote button says *"This answer is not useful"*